# Why is a variable from separate file coming into a file as null when I don't have it set as null?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm setting a variable in a stateful widget equal to a String from another file. I want this to only be set the first time the user starts the program as it can be changed later on. The only issue is that the variable comes in as null when I have it set to not null where it's declared. Anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to fix this? Thanks!

This is where I declare the variable currentSelectedType. I set it as "Equal Value". Now when I try to set another variable equal to it in another file where it's imported it says it's null. There's also the resetData function which I use at times to clear out the values. But it shouldn't be causing my issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';


TextEditingController amountEditingController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController descriptionEditingController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController dataEditingController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController rateEditingController = TextEditingController();
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
String currentSelectedType = "Equal Value";

resetData() {
  amountEditingController = TextEditingController();
  descriptionEditingController = TextEditingController();
  payeeEditingController = TextEditingController();
  rateEditingController = TextEditingController();
  selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  currentSelectedType = null;

}
```

This is the bit where I try to set holder equal to the currentSelectedType variable which is declared in the other file (The other file is called variable_data and is imported as Data). But currentSelectedType is null here. Which is my issue. I'm expecting it to be what I declared it as at first, not null. I just gotta be able to set the holder equal to its initial value.

```
import 'package:testproject/widgetdata/variable_data.dart' as Data;

class InsertDataDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InsertDataDrawerState createState() => _InsertDataDrawerState();
}

class _InsertDataDrawerState extends State<InsertDataDrawer> {
  String selectedDate;
  var deviceTypes = [''];
  var dropTypes = recurring_type;
  String holder = Data.currentSelectedType;
```

Slimmed down code on how the reset data function is called

```
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .85,
                      height: 50,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        child: Text("Save Data"),
                        onPressed: () {
                          submitData();
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
```

```
  submitData() async {
    Data.resetData();
    Navigator.pop(context);
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: "Data successfully submitted",
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 15 );
  }
```

Comment: Where are you calling the resetData function? Are you calling resetData() in initState?

Comment: I call it in a function that is triggered by a user tapping a button.

Comment: How are you calling the function can you show? Are you calling it like RaisedButton(onPressed : resetData(), child: Text("Reset"));

Comment: Added snippets to the question to show how its called

Comment: (1) Add a print("called") statement as the first line of code in submitData() function. Just to debug if it is being called from somewhere within the code. (2) Have you defined something else as Data too?

Comment: Definitely only gets called once, upon the button press. Tested it with the print statement. I only have the variable_data file defined as Data in this file also.  Am I declaring it initially incorrectly maybe? Not sure to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what the issue was, definitely not in the code. A full restart of my computer resolved it though.